# No puedo usar la función "bind" de Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Al poner "variable.bind(parametro1, parametro2)" no me deja compilar por el error: "this.bind is not a function"

```html
for(let file of fs.readdirSync('./events/')){
  if(file.endsWith('.js')){
    let fileName = file.substring(0, file.length - 3);
    let fileContent = require(`./events/${file}`);

    client.on(fileName, fileContent.bind(null, client))

    delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./events/${file}`)];
  }

}
```

No estoy seguro si es por los parámetros que uso o un error mío de comprensión de la función.

Comment: ¿Qué es `fileContent`? ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo del contenido de ese módulo?

Comment: El programa es para un bot de discord, entonces basicamente fileContent va a guardar los archivos que se encuentren en la carpeta "Events" que son archivos JS con eventos que va a ejecutar el bot, el más sencillo es uno así:

module.exports = async(client) => {
    console.log("Estoy listo!");
}